# Konva and perspectivets integration

Tags: react-konva, konva

I have a React project involving image perspective management using perspective.ts in a custom polygon I draw using Konva.

I would like to be able to drag the shape and move individual dots to change the shape and update the new image accordingly.

A "working" [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-ts-forked-3h4ccj?file=/src/App.tsx).

The idea is that I have an array of dots ({x: number, y: number}), I update their position on Drag and draw line between dots. I use perspective ts to apply the image to the image context with sceneFunc.

The problem is that if I try to move one of the dot "outside" its original position on top and left, it fills the remaining space with white background.

I tried to change the coordinates on the canvas in a useEffect when dots are moved, I tried to create a new canvas and apply polygon attributes to it... Nothing seems to fix this specific problem but I'm probably looking in the bad direction.

Any help is appreciated ! (maybe [@lavrton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/512042/lavrton) ?)

Comment: Well, I played with it. I thought, `perspectivets` library doesn't like negative values. I made this version: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-konva-ts-forked-22h8g7?file=/src/App.tsx:220-233
But still in some cases it doesn't work. And I am not sure why. Need to dive in into perspectivets internals.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer. I came to the same conclusion... A clumsy workaround is to initialize the dots positions in the middle of the canvas instead of 0,0 in order to have more room to play with the shape.
Anyway, a real solution is to do the perspective maths by hand to ease integration with Konva.